# Stack overflow when creating monochrome PNG images

Tags: haskell, png, stack-overflow

I found a small library for writing PNG files using Haskell on [this page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Library/PNG). I just rearranged it so that it supports all monochrome, grayscale and RGB outputs.

However, it seems that I always get stack overflow when writing large monochrome images, but not if I use grayscale or RGB. In this example, the size threshold is more or less 2000: if I set `width` less than that, the image is generated, otherwise I get a stack overflow.

```
import Png

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

width = 2000 :: Int

main = do
  let setG = [ [ (r + c) `mod` 256 | c <- [0..width]] | r <- [0..width]]
  let outputG = pngGrayscale setG
  putStrLn "Writing grayscale image..."
  B.writeFile "grayscale.png" outputG
  putStrLn "Done"

  let setR = [ [ (r `mod` 256, c `mod` 256, (r+c) `mod` 256) | c <- [0..width]] | r <- [0..width]]
  let outputR = pngRGB setR
  putStrLn "Writing RGB image..."
  B.writeFile "rgb.png" outputR
  putStrLn "Done"

  let setM = [ [ even (r + c) | c <- [0..width]] | r <- [0..width]]
  let outputM = pngMonochrome setM
  putStrLn "Writing monochrome image..."
  B.writeFile "monochrome.png" outputM
  putStrLn "done"
```

Since the only significant difference between the three functions `png*` seems to be the call to `bitpack*`, I suppose this is the culprit, but I have no idea how to fix that.

This is the library (the original can be found [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Library/PNG)):

```
{-
A small library for creating monochrome PNG files.
This file is placed into the public domain.
Dependencies: Zlib.
-}
module Png (pngRGB, pngGrayscale, pngMonochrome) where
import Data.Array
import Data.Bits
import Data.List
import Data.Word
import qualified Codec.Compression.Zlib as Z
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

import Control.DeepSeq (deepseq)

be8 :: Word8 -> B.ByteString
be8 x = B.singleton x

be32 :: Word32 -> B.ByteString
be32 x = B.pack [fromIntegral (x `shiftR` sh) | sh <- [24,16,8,0]]

pack :: String -> B.ByteString
pack xs = B.pack $ map (fromIntegral.fromEnum) xs

unpack :: B.ByteString -> String
unpack xs = map (toEnum.fromIntegral) (B.unpack xs)

hdr, iHDR, iDAT, iEND :: B.ByteString
hdr = pack "\137\80\78\71\13\10\26\10"
iHDR = pack "IHDR"
iDAT = pack "IDAT"
iEND = pack "IEND"

chunk :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString -> [B.ByteString]
chunk tag xs = [be32 (fromIntegral $ B.length xs), dat, be32 (crc dat)]
    where dat = B.append tag xs

-- | Return a monochrome PNG file from a two dimensional bitmap
-- stored in a list of lines represented as a list of booleans.
pngMonochrome :: [[Bool]] -> B.ByteString
pngMonochrome dat = B.concat $ hdr : concat [ihdr, imgdat, iend]
    where height = fromIntegral $ length dat
          width = fromIntegral $ length (head dat)
          ihdr = chunk iHDR (B.concat [
                be32 width, be32 height, be8 1, be8 0, be8 0, be8 0, be8 0])
          imgdat = chunk iDAT (Z.compress imgbits)
          imgbits = B.concat $ map scanlineMonochrome dat
          iend = chunk iEND B.empty

scanlineMonochrome :: [Bool] -> B.ByteString
scanlineMonochrome dat = 0 `B.cons` bitpackMonochrome dat

bitpackMonochrome' :: [Bool] -> Word8 -> Word8 -> B.ByteString
bitpackMonochrome' [] n b = if b /= 0x80 then B.singleton n else B.empty
bitpackMonochrome' (x:xs) n b =
    if b == 1
        then v `B.cons` bitpackMonochrome' xs 0 0x80
        else bitpackMonochrome' xs v (b `shiftR` 1)
    where v = if x then n else n .|. b

bitpackMonochrome :: [Bool] -> B.ByteString
bitpackMonochrome xs = bitpackMonochrome' xs 0 0x80

crc :: B.ByteString -> Word32
crc xs = updateCrc 0xffffffff xs `xor` 0xffffffff

updateCrc :: Word32 -> B.ByteString -> Word32
updateCrc = B.foldl' crcStep

crcStep :: Word32 -> Word8 -> Word32
crcStep crc ch = (crcTab ! n) `xor` (crc `shiftR` 8)
    where n = fromIntegral (crc `xor` fromIntegral ch)

crcTab :: Array Word8 Word32
crcTab = listArray (0,255) $ flip map [0..255] (\n ->
    foldl' (\c k -> if c .&. 1 == 1
                      then 0xedb88320 `xor` (c `shiftR` 1)
                      else c `shiftR` 1) n [0..7])




white, black :: Int
white = 255
black = 0

-- | Produces a single grayscale bit given a percent black
gray :: Int -> Int
gray percent = 255 - floor (fromIntegral percent * 2.55)

-- | Return a grayscale PNG file from a two dimensional bitmap stored in a list
-- of lines represented as a list of 0-255 integer values.
pngGrayscale :: [[Int]] -> B.ByteString
pngGrayscale dat = B.concat $ hdr : concat [ihdr, imgdat, iend]
     where height = fromIntegral $ length dat
           width = fromIntegral $ length (head dat)
           ihdr = chunk iHDR $ B.concat
                     [ be32 width
                     , be32 height
                     , be8 8   -- bits per pixel
                     , be8 0   -- color type
                     , be8 0   -- compression method
                     , be8 0   -- filter method
                     , be8 0 ] -- interlace method
           imgdat = chunk iDAT (Z.compress imgbits)
           imgbits = B.concat $ map scanlineGrayscale dat
           iend = chunk iEND B.empty

scanlineGrayscale :: [Int] -> B.ByteString
scanlineGrayscale dat = B.pack (0 : map fromIntegral dat)






-- | Return a RGB PNG file from a two dimensional bitmap stored in a list
-- of lines represented as a list of triples of 0-255 integer values.
pngRGB :: [[(Int,Int,Int)]] -> B.ByteString
pngRGB dat = B.concat $ hdr : concat [ihdr, imgdat ,iend]
     where height = fromIntegral $ length dat
           width = fromIntegral $ length (head dat)
           ihdr = chunk iHDR $ B.concat
                     [ be32 height
                     , be32 width
                     , be8 8   -- bits per sample (8 for r, 8 for g, 8 for b)
                     , be8 2   -- color type (2=rgb)
                     , be8 0   -- compression method
                     , be8 0   -- filter method
                     , be8 0 ] -- interlace method
           imgdat = chunk iDAT (Z.compress imagedata)
           imagedata = B.concat $ map scanlineRGB dat
           iend = chunk iEND B.empty

scanlineRGB :: [(Int,Int,Int)] -> B.ByteString
scanlineRGB dat = B.pack (0 : (map fromIntegral $ concatMap (\(r,g,b) -> [r,g,b]) dat))
```

Comment: By "monochrome" you mean binary black-white?

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, I mean 1-bit per pixel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit is

```
bitpackMonochrome' :: [Bool] -> Word8 -> Word8 -> B.ByteString
bitpackMonochrome' [] n b = if b /= 0x80 then B.singleton n else B.empty
bitpackMonochrome' (x:xs) n b =
    if b == 1
        then v `B.cons` bitpackMonochrome' xs 0 0x80
        else bitpackMonochrome' xs v (b `shiftR` 1)
    where v = if x then n else n .|. b
```

which uses `B.cons` to concatenate `ByteString`s. That is rather inefficient anyway, and `B.cons` is strict in its second argument.

Therefore, you get a huge (about half a million deep for a `2000×2000` bit image) thunk of the form

```
v1 `B.cons` (v2 `B.cons` (v3 ...)))
```

that overflows the stack.

A simple cure - that still is rather inefficient - is to use lists in `bitpackMonochrome'`, since `(:)` is lazy in its second argument,

```
bitpackMonochrome :: [Bool] -> B.ByteString
bitpackMonochrome xs = B.pack $ bitpackMonochrome' xs 0 0x80

bitpackMonochrome' :: [Bool] -> Word8 -> Word8 -> [Word8]
bitpackMonochrome' [] n b = if b /= 0x80 then [n] else []
bitpackMonochrome' (x:xs) n b =
    if b == 1
        then v : bitpackMonochrome' xs 0 0x80
        else bitpackMonochrome' xs v (b `shiftR` 1)
    where v = if x then n else n .|. b
```

and `B.pack` that in `bitpackMonochrome`.

This way, you don't get the huge thunk, since the `(:)` can be evaluated before its second argument.

A much more efficient version would calculate the needed size from the dimensions and use

```
create :: Int -> (Ptr Word8 -> IO ()) -> IO ByteString
```

or even

```
unsafeCreate :: Int -> (Ptr Word8 -> IO ()) -> ByteString
```

from `Data.ByteString.Internal` to directly fill the allocated buffer of the correct size.